# Insert a line break from Excel VBA in a Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

From my Excel Sheet I open up a Word document. Excel generates some text within the document. Between the text I want a LineBreak. 
The code results in an error message stating: *parameter value out of acceptable range*

Using the following  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertbreak) this should be possible using InsertBreak.

```
Sub InsertLineBreak()
    Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Open Word
    Set objDoc = wrd.Documents.Add 'Add new document
    Set objSelection = wrd.Selection 'Select this document

    objSelection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak 'Insert Break
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your Excel VBA know the value of `wdLineBreak` ?  Have you added a reference to the Word object library?  If not, you need to define any Word constants in your code.

Comment: @TimWilliams How could I have known it was missing? What do you suggest setting a reference or defining the Word constants?

Comment: If you use `Option Explicit` (and you should *always* use that) then you will get warnings about this type of problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works perfectly fine for me, are you sure you have added correct reference?

Try `objSelection.InsertBreak Type:=6` or add `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library` reference, or declare a globar variable `wdLineBreak`

Comment: it was indeed the lib was missing. What is the value of declaring `wdLineBreak` as global?

Comment: Cool, the value of `wdLineBreak` is 6

Comment: @JeroenDV there isn’t any value in declaring wdLineBreak as a global. It only needs to be a constant in the routine where it is used, assuming you are using late binding.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers:

In this case the `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library` was missing. 
It can be added `Tools`-> `References` and selecting the corresponding Library

[image: Word Object Lib]